# Edit on child gridview collapse the expansion

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, nested-gridview

I have a parent grid GVInvoiceDet. CRUD operation on this grid is working fine. In each row of the parent, I have child grid GVTaxDetails which opens on click of image ie expand/collapse feature.

I am looking for CRUD within child grid also. But when I click on edit within child, the texbox for editing doesn't appear and the parent grid collapses.

Here is child grid rowediting code

```
protected void GVTaxDetails_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView gvTemp = (GridView)sender;
            gvUniqueID = gvTemp.UniqueID;
            //gvEditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
            gvTemp.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
            GVInvoiceDet.DataBind();           
        }
```

Parent row editing code

```
protected void GVInvoiceDet_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
            GVInvoiceDet.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
            GVInvoiceDet.DataBind();
            BindItemGrid();          
        }
```

ASPX file :

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GVInvoiceDet" runat="server" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        HorizontalAlign="Left" BorderStyle="Outset" OnRowCancelingEdit="GVInvoiceDet_RowCancelingEdit"
        OnRowEditing="GVInvoiceDet_RowEditing" OnRowDataBound="GVInvoiceDet_RowDataBound" ShowFooter="True"
        OnRowCommand="GVInvoiceDet_RowCommand" OnRowUpdating="GVInvoiceDet_RowUpdating"
        OnRowDeleting="GVInvoiceDet_RowDeleting" OnRowDeleted="GVInvoiceDet_RowDeleted"
        OnRowUpdated="GVInvoiceDet_RowUpdated" AllowSorting="True" DataSourceID="DSItemGrid" DataKeyNames="invoiceno,itemcd">
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#0000ff" ForeColor="Yellow" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" ForeColor="#330099" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" ForeColor="#330099" />
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#FE9CD5" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <a href="javascript:expandcollapse('div<%# Eval("itemcd") %>', 'one');">
                        <img id="imgdiv<%# Eval("itemcd") %>" alt="Click to show/hide Tax Details <%# Eval("itemcd") %>" border="0" src="Images/plus.png" />
                    </a>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="10%" HeaderText="Item Code" SortExpression="itemcd">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblItemCode" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("itemcd")%>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtItemCode" Width="90%" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("itemcd")%>' Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtItemCode" Width="90%" runat="server" Text='' Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="10%" HeaderText="HSN Code" SortExpression="hsncd">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblItemHSNCode" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("hsncd")%>'></asp:Label><asp:HiddenField ID="hdnItemGST" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("itempercentage") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtItemHSN" Width="90%" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("hsncd")%>' Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox><asp:HiddenField ID="hdnEditItemGST" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("itempercentage") %>' />
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtItemHSN" Width="90%" runat="server" Text='' Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox><asp:HiddenField ID="hdnFooterItemGST" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("itempercentage") %>' />
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="25%" HeaderText="Item Description" SortExpression="itemdesc">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblItemDesc" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("itemdesc")%>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblItemDesc" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("itemdesc")%>' Visible="false"></asp:Label><asp:HiddenField ID="hdnItemDesc" runat="server" Value='<%# String.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}",Eval("itemcd"),Eval("hsncd"),Eval("itempercentage")) %>' />
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="eddlItemDesc" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="eddlItemDesc_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="fddlItemDesc" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="fddlItemDesc_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="5%" HeaderText="Quantity">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblItemQty" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("quantity")%>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtItemQty" Width="90%" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("quantity")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtItemQty" Width="90%" MaxLength="100" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="5%" HeaderText="Unit Rate">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblItemUnitRate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("unitrate")%>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtItemUnitRate" Width="90%" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("unitrate")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtItemUnitRate" Width="90%" MaxLength="100" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="5%" HeaderText="Unit Value">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblItemUnitValue" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("unitvalue")%>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtItemUnitValue" Width="90%" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("unitvalue")%>' Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtItemUnitValue" Width="90%" MaxLength="100" runat="server" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="5%" HeaderText="Final Value">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblItemFinalValue" runat="server" Text=''></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtItemFinalValue" Width="90%" runat="server" Text='' Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtItemFinalValue" Width="90%" MaxLength="100" runat="server" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" HeaderText="Edit" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete" ItemStyle-Width="5%">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="linkDeleteInvoiceItem" CommandName="DeleteItem" runat="server">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="linkAddInvoiceItem" CommandName="AddItem" runat="server">Add</asp:LinkButton>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="100%">
                            <div id="div<%# Eval("itemcd") %>" style="display: none; position: relative; left: 15px; overflow: auto; width: 97%">
                                <asp:GridView ID="GVTaxDetails" BackColor="White" Width="100%" Font-Size="Small" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                                    runat="server" DataKeyNames="invoiceno,itemcd,valuecd" ShowFooter="True" OnRowUpdating="GVTaxDetails_RowUpdating"
                                    OnRowCommand="GVTaxDetails_RowCommand" OnRowEditing="GVTaxDetails_RowEditing" GridLines="None"
                                    OnRowUpdated="GVTaxDetails_RowUpdated" OnRowCancelingEdit="GVTaxDetails_CancelingEdit"
                                    OnRowDataBound="GVTaxDetails_RowDataBound" OnRowDeleting="GVTaxDetails_RowDeleting" OnRowDeleted="GVTaxDetails_RowDeleted"
                                    ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" BorderStyle="Double" BorderColor="#0083C1">
                                    <RowStyle BackColor="Gainsboro" />
                                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#0083C1" ForeColor="White" />
                                    <FooterStyle BackColor="White" />
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="5%" HeaderText="SL No">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblViewTaxSlno" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("slno")%>'></asp:Label>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtViewTaxSlno" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("slno")%>' Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </EditItemTemplate>
                                            <FooterTemplate>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtViewTaxSlno" MaxLength="3" Width="80%" runat="server" Text='<%# Convert.ToInt32(Container.DataItemIndex) + 1 %>' Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </FooterTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="15%" HeaderText="Value">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnViewTaxDesc" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("valuecd") %>' />
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblViewTaxDesc" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("valuedesc")%>'></asp:Label>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnViewTaxDesc" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("valuecd") %>' />
                                                <asp:DropDownList ID="eddlViewTaxDesc" Width="90%" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="eddViewTaxDesc_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
                                            </EditItemTemplate>
                                            <FooterTemplate>
                                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnViewTaxDesc" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("valuecd") %>' />
                                                <asp:DropDownList ID="fddViewTaxDesc" Width="90%" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="fddlViewTaxDesc_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
                                            </FooterTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="3%" HeaderText="Amount">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblViewTaxAmount" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("value")%>'></asp:Label>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtViewTaxAmount" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("value")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                                            </EditItemTemplate>
                                            <FooterTemplate>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtViewTaxAmount" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("value")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                                            </FooterTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="7%" HeaderText="Ref. Sl No">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblViewTaxRefNo" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("refslno")%>'></asp:Label>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnViewTaxRefNo" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("refslno") %>' />
                                                <asp:DropDownList ID="eddlViewTaxRefNo" Width="90%" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false"></asp:DropDownList>
                                            </EditItemTemplate>
                                            <FooterTemplate>
                                                <asp:DropDownList ID="fddViewTaxRefNo" Width="90%" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false"></asp:DropDownList>
                                            </FooterTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="10%" HeaderText="Tax-Mode">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblViewTaxMode" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("absper").ToString()=="A"?"Absolute":"Percentage"%>'></asp:Label>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnViewTaxMode" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("absper") %>' />
                                                <asp:DropDownList ID="eddlViewTaxMode" Width="90%" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false">
                                                    <asp:ListItem Value="-1" Text="-Select Mode-" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Value="A" Text="Absolute"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Value="P" Text="Percentage"></asp:ListItem>
                                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                            </EditItemTemplate>
                                            <FooterTemplate>
                                                <asp:DropDownList ID="fddlViewTaxMode" Width="95%" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false">
                                                    <asp:ListItem Value="-1" Text="-Select Mode-" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Value="A" Text="Absolute"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Value="P" Text="Percentage"></asp:ListItem>
                                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                            </FooterTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="10%" HeaderText="Operation">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblViewTaxOperation" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("addsub").ToString()=="A"?"Add":"Subtract"%>'></asp:Label>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnViewTaxOperation" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("addsub") %>' />
                                                <asp:DropDownList ID="eddlViewTaxOperation" Width="90%" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false">
                                                    <asp:ListItem Value="-1" Text="-Select Operation-" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Value="A" Text="Add"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Value="S" Text="Subtract"></asp:ListItem>
                                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                            </EditItemTemplate>
                                            <FooterTemplate>
                                                <asp:DropDownList ID="fddlViewTaxOperation" Width="90%" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false">
                                                    <asp:ListItem Value="-1" Text="-Select Operation-" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Value="A" Text="Add"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Value="S" Text="Subtract"></asp:ListItem>
                                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                            </FooterTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="3%" HeaderText="Final Amount">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblViewTaxFinalAmount" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("finalvalue")%>'></asp:Label>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtViewTaxFinalAmount" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("finalvalue")%>' Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </EditItemTemplate>
                                            <FooterTemplate>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtViewTaxFinalAmount" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("finalvalue")%>' Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </FooterTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Edit" ShowEditButton="True" />
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:LinkButton ID="linkDeleteTaxDetails" CommandName="Delete" runat="server">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                            <FooterTemplate>
                                                <asp:LinkButton ID="linkAddTaxDetails" CommandName="AddTax" runat="server">Add</asp:LinkButton>
                                            </FooterTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                    </Columns>
                                </asp:GridView>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="DSItemGrid" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:GSTCS %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:GSTCS.ProviderName %>"
        SelectCommand="select invoiceno, dt.itemcd itemcd, mast.itemdesc itemdesc, mast.hsncd hsncd, dt.quantity quantity, 
        mast.unitrate unitrate, dt.unitvalue unitvalue, mast.itempercentage itempercentage   
        from GSTINVOICEDT dt join GSTITEMMASTER mast on (dt.itemcd = mast.itemcd and dt.unitcode = mast.unitcode and dt.projectcode = mast.projectcode) 
        where dt.unitcode = :unitCode and dt.projectCode = :projCode and dt.invoiceno = :invoiceNo order by invoiceno, itemcd">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="05" Name="unitCode" SessionField="unit" />
            <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="0501" Name="projCode" SessionField="project" />
            <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="INVOICENO" Name="invoiceNo" SessionField="invoiceNo" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the work done... Posting the code for others if come across similar situation.

In parent rowdatabound have added code to keep the div open and update the editIndex.

```
protected void GVInvoiceDet_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) {
            GridViewRow row = e.Row;
            if(row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
            {
                return;
            }
            else if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow )
            {
                   //Find Child GridView control
                    GridView gvTax = new GridView();
                    gvTax = (GridView)row.FindControl("GVTaxDetails");
                    if (gvTax.UniqueID == gvUniqueID)
                    {
                        gvTax.EditIndex = gvEditIndex;
                        //Expand the Child grid
                        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Expand", "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='javascript'>expandcollapse('div" + ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem)["itemcd"].ToString() + "','one');</script>");
                    }
            }
  }
```

expandcollapse is function on aspx side:

```
function expandcollapse(obj, row) {
            var div = document.getElementById(obj);
            var img = document.getElementById('img' + obj);

            if (div.style.display == "none") {
                div.style.display = "block";
                if (row == 'alt') {
                    img.src = "Images/minus.png";
                }
                else {
                    img.src = "Images/minus.png";
                }
                img.alt = "Close View Taxes";
            }
            else {
                div.style.display = "none";
                if (row == 'alt') {
                    img.src = "Images/plus.png";
                }
                else {
                    img.src = "Images/plus.png";
                }
                img.alt = "Expand View Taxes";
            }
        }
```